# How to index and query a very large DB with 60M rows and 50 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

[image: EXPLAIN SQL]I have a big table with 60M rows and 50 columns (columns include "company_idx" and "timestamp"). Thus, when I do my simple SQL Query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM companies_Scores.Scores 
WHERE `company_idx`=11 
  AND `timestamp` BETWEEN  '"+start_date+" 00:00:00' AND '"+end_date+" 00:00:00'
```

It takes basically 4 minutes to run (which is way too long).
Thus, I thought about indexing my table, so I've done:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_time ON companies_Scores.Scores(company_idx, timestamp) USING BTREE;
```

However, when I now do the following, it takes also 4 minutes to run.

```
SELECT * FROM companies_Scores.Scores 
USE INDEX(idx_time) 
WHERE `company_idx`=11 
  AND `timestamp` BETWEEN  '"+start_date+" 00:00:00' AND '"+end_date+" 00:00:00'
```

I'm really a beginner with SQL and indexes. So I'm not really sure how to use indexes in a query. I guess the one I've done above is correct? Why does it take so much time? How can I improve it?
I'd like my queries for each company_idx to be as quick as possible.

When I run EXPLAIN, I get:

```
[{'Cardinality': 115751,
  'Collation': 'A',
  'Column_name': 'company_idx',
  'Comment': '',
  'Index_comment': '',
  'Index_type': 'BTREE',
  'Key_name': 'idx_time',
  'Non_unique': 1,
  'Null': 'YES',
  'Packed': None,
  'Seq_in_index': 1,
  'Sub_part': None,
  'Table': 'Scores'},
 {'Cardinality': 45831976,
  'Collation': 'A',
  'Column_name': 'timestamp',
  'Comment': '',
  'Index_comment': '',
  'Index_type': 'BTREE',
  'Key_name': 'idx_time',
  'Non_unique': 1,
  'Null': 'YES',
  'Packed': None,
  'Seq_in_index': 2,
  'Sub_part': None,
  'Table': 'Scores'}]
```

Comment: What does this have to do with python? Please only add relevant tags (removed)

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN ..` on the query and add the details of the same to question. Also, do you really need to do `SELECT * ..` ? Do read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/2469308)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya i've updated my question

Comment: @mike.depetriconi This does not look like result of `EXPLAIN ..` statement. Are you sure that you are using MySQL ? Please run `EXPLAIN <your complete select query here>`

Comment: sorry just added the output as an image

Comment: @mike.depetriconi `USE INDEX` is just a hint; it does not force MySQL to use that index only. Instead try running the query with `FORCE INDEX(...)`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya it looks like it improved by a minute. But my request still takes 3 minutes to run. How can I do?

Comment: @mike.depetriconi The data you are trying to fetch in a single query is too big. Do you really need to get all these thousands (or maybe millions) of rows at once. Generally, we use `LIMIT ..` clause and use pagination. Also, do you really need to do `SELECT *` ? Why not just fetch the relevant fields only

Comment: Here I would suggest instead of index use MySql [Range Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-range.html) that will definately increase perform. Partition your taable on timestamp (may be month wise or year wise whichever has less data) and don't forgot to use timestamp condition as first condition in where clause.

Comment: @SantoshD. - If it can use `INDEX(country_idx, timestamp)`, then no flavor of partitioning will run any faster.

Answer (score 0):

Your index looks correct for the query.  You are forcing index usage, so we can assume the index is being used, if possible.

One issue may be that the index cannot be used.  That would occur if you have type problems with the columns.  For instance, the comparison value `11` is a number.  If `customer_idx` is a string, you have a problem.  The comparison should be a string -- `'11'`.

Another issue is simply that there might be a lot of data.  If even a few percent of the rows match the conditions, the index is not going to help.  One major use of indexes is for "needle-in-the-haystack" queries.  They help finding a small subset.  They don't help if you need all or much of the haystack.

Comment: `company_idx` is varchar(20), and in my query 11 is a str too. 
I'm retrieving around 3600 rows of data on every query (so it's a relatively small subset out of 60M rows, right?)

Comment: @mike.depetriconi . . . 3600 rows may or may not be small, depending on how many pages need to be read.  4 minutes seems like a long time to read 3600 pages, but some time makes sense.

Comment: @mike.depetriconi - You did not write it as a string!  Add the quotes are try again!